# push engine in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to code a simple push engine in tornado. 
Basically, I have a program running on my server, continuously producing an output that I process by Python to update a dictionary, and I want that dictionary published to web client, for example every minute.

I would be thankful if your answer contains links to documentation, or rephrasing of my own question. I am reading with a lot of pain tornado documentation, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is a skeleton of the code with comments inside explaining what I want to do:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import pprint

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

# this is to run my bash process and continuously yiled its output
def runProcess(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        retcode = p.poll()
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        yield line
     if retcode is not None:
         break


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #What can I do here if I want to send the update data every minute?
        self.write(data)


    def get_data(self):
        data = dict()
        cmd =  'myProg --args' 
        # this program will produce a continuous stream of data
        for line in runProcess(cmd.split()):
            data[line.split()[0] = line.plit()[1]
        #now dictionary is updated? yield result?
        # even if I want to publish updates every minute?
        yield all_data


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Is `get_data()` running globally for your entire application (as in, every client gets the same data), or is it running per-connection?

Comment: Hi Blender, get_data is running globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@BorrajaX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40428151/464744) suggested, use WebSockets. There are many examples online for how to connect to websockets with JavaScript, so you can figure that part out on your own.

One major issue with your code is that your method for reading lines of text from your process's stdout is blocking, which breaks the way Tornado works. Your code has to hook into the event loop and defer all of the waiting to Tornado itself. Fortunately, Tornado already has a [`process` module](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html) that wraps `subprocess.Popen` so that it supports the `IOStream` interface:

```
@coroutine
def get_data():
    process = Subprocess(['tail', '-f', '/var/log/system.log'], stdout=Subprocess.STREAM)

    while True:
        line = yield process.stdout.read_until('\n')

        # Do something with `line`
```

One other thing to note is that in order to broadcast messages to all the connected websocket clients, you first need to actually keep track of them. This can be done easily by implementing the `open` and `on_close` methods:

```
class BroadcastHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []

    def open(self):
        self.clients.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        self.clients.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def broadcast(cls, message):
        for client in cls.clients:
            client.write_message(message)
```

Once you have that, the `# Do something with line` part becomes quite simple:

```
BroadcastHandler.broadcast(line)
```

Here's something to start off with:

```
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.process import Subprocess


@coroutine
def get_data():
    process = Subprocess(['tail', '-f', '/var/log/system.log'], stdout=Subprocess.STREAM)

    while True:
        line = yield process.stdout.read_until('\n')
        BroadcastHandler.broadcast(line)


class BroadcastHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    clients = []

    def open(self):
        self.clients.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        self.clients.remove(self)

    @classmethod
    def broadcast(cls, message):
        for client in cls.clients:
            client.write_message(message)


def create_application():
    # "Run" the future whenever we start the IOLoop and ignore the result
    IOLoop.instance().add_future(get_data(), lambda _: None)

    app = Application([
        (r'/broadcast', BroadcastHandler),
    ])

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_application()
    app.listen(8888)

    IOLoop.current().start()
```

This method for keeping track of clients is inefficient, but it is good enough for a few hundred clients connecting for long periods of time.

Comment: TIL I didn't know about the tornado's own Subprocess **:+1:**

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, can you please explain why do you say that my method for reading lines from my process is blocking? Indeed as it is wrapped in my runProcess function, yielding one line at a time, I thought it is not blocking.

Comment: @volatile `p.stdout.readline()` is blocking. Try to make another Python script that prints out a line and sleeps for 5 seconds over and over. If you run it with your method, Tornado will not be able to do anything until that blocking call returns.

Answer (score 5):

If your client is a web browser, this sounds like a good fit for [websockets](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html).

Below you'll find a very very simple example. You should add extra checks, as do an actual verification of the connection's [origin](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.check_origin), error handling if the web socket is closed (which can happen... very, very often)

**1)** Tornado server (file `stack_073.py`):

```
import datetime
import time

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket


def get_data():
    return {
        "current_time": datetime.datetime.strftime(
            datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        )
    }


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")
        while True:
            data = get_data()
            self.write_message(data)
            time.sleep(1)


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/websocket", WebSocketHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Now, the HTML (+Javascript) that connects to the websocket and receives the Pushes:

**2)** Web client (file `stack_073.html`):

```
<html>
    <header>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/websocket");
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                var current_time_str = JSON.parse(evt.data)['current_time'];
                document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = current_time_str;
            };
        </script>
    </header>

    <body>
        <p id="date"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you launch your Tornado server on a terminal, and then open the `stack_073.html` file, you should see that the time getting updated every second. There's no Javascript timer or anything, as you can see (the update comes from the `write_message` performed by Tornado)

This will basically create an eternally pending request from the browser to the server, which the server can use to push data to the browser:

[image]

**EDIT 01** (as per the OP's comment to this answer):

> what if get_data is a function that should be called once at first connection, and then run forever [ . . . ] Does replacing the return statement by a yield statement there solve this problem?

Pretty much, yeah. Is just that in that case, your `get_data` returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), but yep. Look at these two changes:

```
def get_data():
    while True:
        yield {
            "current_time": datetime.datetime.strftime(
                datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            )
        }
        time.sleep(1)


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")
        while True:
            data = next(get_data())
            self.write_message(data)
```

**EDIT 02** (as per the OP's comment to this answer):

> I cannot see where in your code is the html file served. When I try it I get a 404 error in the browser

In order to serve your page with Tornado, you need a *regular* (not websocket) handler, to handle the HTTP request to fetch the "initial" web page. Keep in mind that the `websocket` handler is only intended to deal with a [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (the connection that in the Javascript is opened through `var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/websocket");`)

The aforementioned *initial* page then would pretty much return the code that I manually wrote in the file `stack_073.html`, which is the page that contains the Javascript which subsequently initiates *another* request to the websocket's endpoint (`/websocket`) For instance, you could serve the HTML in http://localhost:8888/script_data by creating this very, very dirty handler:

File `stack_073.py`:

```
import datetime
import time

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket


def get_data():
    while True:
        yield {
            "current_time": datetime.datetime.strftime(
                datetime.datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            )
        }
        time.sleep(1)


class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("WebSocket opened")
        while True:
            data = next(get_data())
            self.write_message(data)


class RegularSocketHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(
            "<html>"
            "    <header>"
            "        <script type=\"text/javascript\">"
            "            var ws = new WebSocket(\"ws://%s/websocket\");"
            "            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {"
            "               var current_time_str = JSON.parse(evt.data)['current_time'];"
            "               document.getElementById(\"date\").innerHTML = current_time_str;"
            "            };"
            "        </script>"
            "    </header>"
            "    <body>"
            "        <p id=\"date\"></p>"
            "    </body>"
            "</html>" % (self.request.host))


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/websocket", WebSocketHandler),
        (r"/script_data", RegularSocketHandler)
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. But what if get_data is a function that should be called once at first connection, and then run forever (imagine it is consuming a continuous data stream and updating a variable). Does replacing the return statement by a yield statement there solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the solution. But I cannot see where in your code is the html file served. When I try it I get a 404 error in the browser

Comment: Oh... is not served by Tornado, actually. I created a `.html` file from scratch. The main "thing" you'd need to do if you wanna serve it, would be creating another handler for the web page itself: One of the handlers would give you the HTML with the javascript that would connect to the _second_ handler (which is the handler for the websocket) So when someone gets, let's say, `http://localhost:8888/script_data`, in your handler for `/script_data`, you'd return the HTML with the Javascript that connects to `/websocket`